# Docker login to Github packages from Codespaces gives access denied

Tags: docker, containers, github-codespaces, github-packages

I am working in Github codespaces and I want to login to github packages.

The below way is working from my laptop,  but when I try to login from Codespaces I get `Error response from daemon: Get "https://ghcr.io/v2/": denied: denied`

```
export GH_TOKEN="<github-personal-access-token>"  
export GH_USER="user-name"
echo "$GH_TOKEN" | docker login ghcr.io -u "$GH_USER" --password-stdin
```

Answer (score 0):

On Github Codespaces use the predefined environment variables in your command:

`echo "$GITHUB_TOKEN" | docker login ghcr.io -u "$GITHUB_USER" --password-stdin`

To see all the environment variables run `env | grep GITHUB`